# How to make a UICollectionViewCell's height to fill all the size of the frame?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to have a CollectionViewCell to fill all the frame of the CollectionView, however I've been unable to accomplished this, instead, it looks like this:
[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef5pg.png)

As you can see, there's a space at the top and the bottom of the uicollectionview frame, that should not appear.

The configuration is the following:

```
//////////////////////////////
    //     Collection View      //
    //////////////////////////////
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let viewHeight = viewContainer.frame.height

    let collectionViewFlowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, viewHeight)
    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
    collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

How can I delete this unwanted spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override UICollectionViewFlowLayout Delegate method and return size equal to collectionview size:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return collectionView.frame.size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you set the `collectionViewFlowLayout` properties you may need to call `invalidateLayout`. I would suggest adopting the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` on your view controller and implement the methods:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return self.collectionView.bounds.size
    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```